# Finding the matrix representation of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is :

The vectors $(2,1)$ and $(1,1)$ form a basis for $R^2$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation satisfying $T(2,1)=(-2,6)$ and $T(1,1)=(0,5)$.

Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis given above

My attempt : let $v$ be a vector in $R^2$

$$
v=c_1(2,1)+c_2(1,1)
$$

Transforming V

$$
Tv = c_1T(2,1)+c_2T(1,1)
$$

Replacing $T(2,1)$ and $T(1,1)$ with their given values in the question

$$
Tv = c_1\begin{bmatrix}-2\\6\end{bmatrix} + c_2\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\5 \end{bmatrix}
$$

So from here we find that

$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 6 \\
0 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is my method wrong, since I've used this method in all of the questions solved and I ended up with the correct answer except for this question where it says that the answer is :

$$T=
\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & -5 \\
14 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have another look at the definition of the matrix of linear transformation. Note in particular that it depends heavily on the bases you choose for the domain and codomain. When they ask for the matrix of $T$ **with respect to the basis given above**, they're looking for the $2\times2$ matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} [T(e_1)] & [T(e_2)] \end{pmatrix}$, where $e_1 = (2,1)$, $e_2 = (1,1)$, and $[v]$ denotes the column vector consisting of the coordinates of $v$ in the given codomain basis. So, for instance, $[T(e_1)] = (a,b)$, where $(-2,6) = T(e_1) = ae_1 + be_2 = (2a + b, a+b)$.

Comment: But Why should I look from a different point of view on here? In different bases there was no problem in my way.

Comment: @Xenidia You were probably computing matrices in the standard bases, which simplifies things considerably.

Comment: Without standard bases I still managed to get the correct answer. This question is an exception where I ended up wrong. Your answer might be correct but It doesn't disprove my approach or at least explain why.

Comment: @Xenidia I don't know what "your approach" is. I'm just using the standard definition of the matrix of a linear map found in any linear algebra textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a linear transformation is determined by a basis of $R^2$, that is, \begin{align*}
(T(e_1), T(e_2)) = (e_1, e_2) A,
\end{align*}
where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $e_1 = (2,1,)$, $e_2=(1,1)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 \\
6 & 5 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-8 & -5 \\
14 & 10 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}